# How to using phpseclib on laravel 5 php

Tags: php, laravel, phpseclib

I'm making an application based laravel that allows it to communicate with a linux server via SSH, I usually use phpseclib to communicate with servers such as rebooting and others, but when I build the application with laravel I could not or would rather not see the way how to integrate with laravel I tried to include manual of php but still could not error Class 'phpseclib\Net\ Net_SSH2' not found, my current code

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    // create ssh account and inserted into database here
    if(Auth::check()) // make sure user has been logging on
    {
      if($dump = DB::table('servers')->where('key', $request->_key)->get())
      {
        if($prices = DB::table('app_data')->get())
        {
          $price = $prices[0]->prices;
          if(DB::table('ssh_users')->where('name', $request->sshname)->where('on_server', $dump[0]->ip)->count() > 0 )
          {
            return view('create')->with('userexist', $request->sshname);
          }
          else
          {
            include(app_path() . "/lib/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php");
            $command = new \phpseclib\Net\Net_SSH2($dump[0]->ip);
            $valid = array(
              'sshuser'     => $request->sshname,
              'sshpass'     => $request->sshpass,
              'sshcreated'  => date('d/m/Y'),
              'sshexpired'  => $request->sshexpired,
              'onserver'    => $dump[0]->name,
              'serveruser'  => $dump[0]->user,
              'serverpass'  => $dump[0]->password,
              'sshprice'    => $price,
              'command'     => $command
            );
            if(DB::table('ssh_users')->insert([
              'name'        => $request->sshname,
              'password'    => $request->sshpass,
              'created_at'  => date('d/m/Y'),
              'expired_on'  => $request->sshexpired,
              'on_server'   => $dump[0]->ip,
              'reseller'    => Auth::user()->name
            ])) {
              return view('create')->with('valid', $valid);
            }
          }
        }
        else
        {
          return view('create')->with('error', $request->sshname);
        }
      }
      else
      {
        return view('create')->with('serverabort', $request->sshname);
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 1:**

Check `/lib/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php` and note what class name is used, it may be `SSH2`, and not `Net_SSH2` (pre PSR-4 namespacing).

Then update the line, e.g. to:

$command = new \phpseclib\Net\SSH2($dump[0]->ip);

**Solution 2:**

Install phpseclib as a composer package

`composer require phpseclib/phpseclib`

Then it will be autoloaded and you won't need the `include()`

Comment: Thank you very much :D that's work after i checked on SSH2.php the class name is SSH2 not Net_SSH2 hehehe, but on http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net is Net_SSH2 X_X, anyway +1 hehe

Comment: @RizalFakhri - it's SSH2 if you're using phpseclib 2.0. If you're using phpseclib 1.0 it's Net_SSH2. phpseclib 2.0 is namespaced whereas 1.0 is not. In that regard tanerkuc's answer seems a bit confused. The sample code he gave you uses namespaces but he's asking you to make sure that the name of the class is the non-namespace'd name...  I think I'm going to edit his answer.

Comment: @neubert thanks that's awesome :D anyway don't worry it has been worked and my project has been complete, you can check on https://github.com/rizalio/sshpanel hehehe thank you :D